# How can I run the smaller Memgraph Platform image (one without MAGE)?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm looking for a Memgraph platform image that has only Memgraph and Memgraph Lab. I don't need MAGE at this time. In [the documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/how-to-guides/work-with-docker) the following images are listed:

There are three Docker images you can use to run Memgraph:

- memgraph-platform - installs the whole Memgraph Platform, which includes:

  - MemgraphDB: the graph database
  - mgconsole: a command-line interface for running queries
  - Memgraph Lab: visual user interface for running queries and visualizing graph data
  - MAGE: an open-source library of graph algorithms and custom Cypher procedures
- memgraph-mage - installs MemgraphDB and MAGE
- memgraph - installs MemgraphDB

Is there an Docker image that has Memgraph and Memgraph Lab only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to go to https://hub.docker.com/r/memgraph/memgraph-platform/tags and find the tag of the Docker image that has what you are looking for. At the moment there is a tag `2.6.6-memgraph2.6.0-lab2.5.0` so this version has waht you need, MemgraphDB and Memgraph Lab.

To run the specific version of the Memgraph Platform Docker image just append the version tag to the image name in the docker run command. In this case, the version tag is :2.6.6-memgraph2.6.0-lab2.5.0.

So the command that you are looking for is:

```
docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 -v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph-platform:2.6.6-memgraph2.6.0-lab2.5.0
```